# Portable Ruby on Rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, usb-drive, portable-applications

I got myself a new 8 gig USB key and I'm looking for a decent solution to have a portable RoR environment to learn on. I did the google on it and found a few possibilities, but I'm curious to hear some real life experiences and opinions. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like [InstantRails](http://instantrails.rubyforge.org), very easy to use, no installer, and does not modify your system environment.

Answer (score 3):

InstantRails was replaced by [BitNami RubyStack] in 2007.

http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack

Answer (score 2):

How to create a portable environment based on RubyInstaller's binaries and Development kit:

http://hcettech.blogspot.pt/2012/05/windows-portable-rails-development.html

Related: [Portable Ruby on Rails environment for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388288/portable-ruby-on-rails-environment-for-windows/10825835#10825835)

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a [portable install of Cygwin](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/sezer/software/cygwin/) would be a good choice.

You'll have a full *nix environment which would give you endless possibilities.  You could easily have Ruby, Rails, Mongrel (or whatever server of choice) as well as a really good editor at your disposal as well.  I would recommend VIM with this [Rails specific VIM configuration](http://github.com/srmoon7/vim/commits/master) (fantastic looks and feel!).

I currently have a similar setup running Cygwin off a jump drive.  I use it mostly for the bash shell, VIM, and using tail to monitor development log files with its nicely color coded syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I found this, and I intend to give it a go this evening:
[Flash Rails](http://rubyforge.org/projects/flashrails)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Windows, I'd go for [Instant Rails](http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/) and [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) (with a JVM for Netbeans).

Netbeans is a bit heavy-weight, but it supports lots of nice rails focused IDE features and is the best IDE for Rails on Windows IMO.

You'll get all of that on a lot less than 1 gig.