# How to update rails offline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to update Rails in a pc without internet connection?

It has Windows XP, if that matter.

Comment: Um, where else could it get the updates? Somewhere you're going to need the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the necessary gems from a computer with internet access, transfer these to the computer you wish to update, and use `gem install ...` to install them.

There are instructions here: [How to install Ruby on Rails on a windows PC](http://angrys0ul.com/blog/2007/04/25/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-a-windows-pc/)

Another option might be to run Rails off a portable external hard drive (or flash drive) that can be moved from one PC to another.  There are a couple of packages, Instant Rails, and Flash Rails, that allow you to have a portable version of Rails on Windows.  Unfortunately they are both a bit out of date as far as Rails versions, so you'll still have some upgrading to do once you install them.  See [Portable Ruby on Rails environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258801/portable-ruby-on-rails-environment).