# Portable Ruby on Rails environment for Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, usb-drive, portable-applications

Somenone asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258801/portable-ruby-on-rails-environment) about two years ago. The answer was InstantRails at that time. But InstantRails seems to be out of date.

Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 5):

[Bitnami](http://bitnami.org/) offers both native and virtual stacks for popular platforms, you might check these out.

Answer (score 4):

I just heard about an [Instant Rails VM that Engineyard made using Vagrant](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/virtualize-this-instant-rails-in-a-virtual-box/)-- it's an Ubuntu virtual box with rails all set up and ready to go. I haven't tried it yet though.

As much as I wish Rails ran better on Windows, giving up and using an Ubuntu VM may be the best thing for your purposes-- it would be very self contained.

Comment: Sounds good... and I will definitely try it! But I would prefer a solution without virtualisation on my usb stick.

Comment: Gotta agree here.  I fought Windows/Ruby for almost a year.  Finally used an Ubuntu VM and can't imagine going back.
While many people are genuinely trying to make Ruby stuff Windows compatible, it's definitely a second class platform and probably always will be.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old at this point in time but I stumbled upon it searching for a similar question today.

The current state of the art appears to be [rubyinstaller.org](http://rubyinstaller.org/)  Both Puppet and Chef are using this runtime on windows.

The runtime takes the form of an installation package, so it's not necessarily USB stick portable, but it does give you the option to install to various directories.  You should be able to simply copy `C:\RubyXXX` to your USB stick, change your `%PATH%` appropriately and run with it.

Hope this information helps.

Answer (score 1):

- Choose and create a directory to contain the portable environment
  `ENV_DIR`
- Download the ruby binary from [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) and put it on
  directory `ENV_DIR\ruby`
- Download the Development Kit extractor from RubyInstaller and
  extract it on directory `ENV_DIR\devkit`

Create a script: `ENV_DIR\setpaths.bat`with the commands:

```
@set PATH=%PATH%;%cd%\ruby\bin
@set PATH=%PATH%;%cd%\devkit\bin
@set PATH=%PATH%;%cd%\devkit\mingw\bin
@set PATH=%PATH%;%cd%\devkit\mingw\libexec\gcc\mingw32\4.5.2
@set PATH=%PATH%;%cd%\devkit\mingw\mingw32\bin
@set PATH=%PATH%;%cd%\devkit\sbin\awk
```

Create a script: `ENV_DIR\console.bat` with the commands:

```
@cmd /K setpaths.bat
```

Now you can now run the console.bat executable and have a console in which you can create and run Rails projects.

Source: http://hcettech.blogspot.pt/2012/05/windows-portable-rails-development.html