# Is it possible to run Ruby and Rails off of local folder without installing them first on Mac OS X?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, macos, rubygems

Is it possible to run Ruby and Rails on Mac OS X off of a local folder (without local or system install using RVM, Homebrew, etc.)

Similar to the way one can copy/paste Java installation directory and just run off of it with no dependencies, I'd like to do the same with Ruby/Rails.

The goal is to be able to connect a USB drive to someone's Mac OS X, open terminal, and demo an application (execute "rails server" from the mounted USB drive) without having to install/compile anything.

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

[Bitnami Ruby Stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/ruby) seems the best way to go for a portable RoR solution

Comment: It seems that an install is required with Bitnami. I'm trying to find a way to run Ruby/Rails without altering the local machine, to run off of a local/mounted path, set environment variables via scripts if needed (for the current terminal session), without a change/install in the machine.

Comment: Then check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258801/portable-ruby-on-rails-environment

Comment: It talks about Windows alternatives, I'm looking for a Mac/Linux solution