# Ruby Script to Runnable File

Tags: ruby, jruby

I'm a programming newb trying to send a Ruby script/mini-game thing to his teacher that can be ran by doubleclick. JRuby seems like a possible solution, as does Warbler, but I can't seem to figure either of those out. It doesn't have to be a specific filetype if it can be run without the terminal, just by clicking on it. Another possible solution is creating a shell script that runs the file as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445664/make-a-ruby-script-with-text-io-double-clickable-executable-file), but I think that only works if you tell the computer running the script that it can be doubleclicked. It may even be possible to run by doing something in the Ruby file itself, but I am too inexperienced to know.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're asking for recommendations. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0):

When you say `that only works if you tell the computer running the script that it can be doubleclicked`, that isn't entirely true. If you email the file by itself, it might have its permissions removed, but if you package it up into a zip, then you're teacher shouldn't need to run `chmod` again.

Anyway, I'm not sure about the windows support for this approach (Ruby programmers tend to use Unix systems like OSX or Linux).

To make a cross platform executable, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855587/packaging-ruby-into-a-portable-executable), which links to some packages such as ["Ruby Ship"](https://github.com/stephan-nordnes-eriksen/ruby_ship)

Comment: I should have specified this earlier, but my teacher and I both use OSX. I'm guessing that would make this easier?